# Add select form value into a textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, textarea

How can I add (and not replace) the **value** of a `select` input **into** a `textarea`.

For instance, I have:

### HTML

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<select id="test">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

If I write *"Stackoverflow"* in the `textarea`, then I choose *Foo* in the `select` input, the `textarea` content should become *"Stackoverflow foo"*.

I tried doing the following

### Javascript

```
$("#text").val()
```

But it seems to replace the content of the textarea instead of adding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#test').on('change',function(){
 var test = this;
 $('#text').val(function(_,v){
     return v + test.value;
 })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just get the current value and add to it

`$("#text").val($("#text").val() + "Foo");`

or EVEN BETTER use `append()`

`$("#text").append("Foo");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [.val( function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value):

```
$("#text").val(function (_, oldValue) {
    return oldValue + $('#test').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, everytime the value of the `select` input **changes**, its selected option text is added to the `textarea`:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    $('#text').val($('#text').val()+" "+$('#test option:selected').text());
});
```

[**See this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpYhF/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").change(function(){
        var textAreaContent = $("#text").val();  //VALUE OF TEXTAREA
        var selectBoxVal = $(this).val();    //VALUE OF SELECT BOX
       $("#text").val(textAreaContent+" "+selectBoxVal);   //ADD THE VALUE INSIDE TEXTAREA
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply in `onChange` function of `select box` write

```
$('#text').val($('#text').val()+'Foo');
```