# Make the value from option select auto-entered to the textarea

Tags: php, html

Is there any way that the value from select option to be auto-inserted into a textarea? (in php)

**Option Select:**

```
<select id="Branch">
  <option value="MCG">MCG</option>
  <option value="KB">KB</option>
  <option value="KT">KT</option>
</select>
```

**TextArea**

```
<input name="street" type=text value=>
```

Sorry in advance if I didn't ask the question correctly

Comment: I think it'll work simple with javascript. see here if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044339/11168176

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using PHP at a time on change select but,
You can select option to be auto-inserted into a textarea using javascript like blow example

```js
function updateTextareaValue(selectVal){
      document.getElementById("street").value = selectVal;   
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="Branch" onchange="updateTextareaValue(this.value);">
            <option value="MCG">MCG</option>
            <option value="KB">KB</option>
            <option value="KT">KT</option>
            <option value="XX">XX</option>
            <option value="YY">YY</option>
        </select>       
        <textarea id="street"></textarea>        
    </body>
</html>
```